# A/V Controls button for Slow motion in QuickTime Player (10.5)?

Tags: mac, audio, video, vlc-media-player, quicktime

I find that Apple answers this question

Slow motion in QuickTime Player (10.5) in Mac?
From https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250493652

> You can use the keyboard shortcuts below for slow motion playback:
> ∙ Continuous press K+L for forward slow motion with audio
> ∙ Continuous press K+J for reverse slow motion with audio

**My question: is there also an A/V Controls button like here explained in** https://filme.imyfone.com/video-editing-tips/how-to-speed-up-videos-on-quicktime-player/?

I did not find such A/V Controls button available.

If not, which versions of QuickTime Player have that QuickTime Player?

Answer (score 1):

Apple discarded a lot of the old "Pro" control & editing aspects when it updated Quicktime 7 to Quicktime 10 [there was no 8 or 9].

Your linked page at imyphone is actually using an old Windows version, equivalent to v7, long abandoned.

You can still get [Quicktime 7](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201288) but I don't know if it will work on any recent macOS. It will also be difficult to get hold of a Pro registration number if you need to activate the higher functionality - you can't buy them any more.

Comment: Thanks!  +1, This "update" seems to be degraded in this aspect ---- do you agree?

Comment: Yes. There were many complaints at the time - one of many changes in the wrong direction as Apple went from making 'professional computers' to 'lifestyle devices'.